# SQL Server Linked Server to Progress is slow with an openquery view

Tags: sql-server, progress-4gl, openedge, openquery

We have a SQL Server database setup with a Linked Server setup connecting to a Progress OpenEdge database. We created a SQL Server view (for using with SSRS) of some of the OpenEdge tables using code similar to the following:

CREATE VIEW accounts AS SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(myLinkedServerName,
'SELECT * FROM PUB.accounts')

CREATE VIEW clients AS SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(myLinkedServerName,
'SELECT * FROM PUB.clients')

For some reason the queries seem to bring back the whole table and then filter on the SQL side instead of executing the query on the Progress side.

Anybody know why or how to remedy the situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is it any faster when executed as a native OpenEdge SQL query?  (You can use the sqlexp command line tool to run the query from a proenv prompt.)

If it is not then the issue may be that you need to run UPDATE STATISTICS on the database.

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/20992

You may also need to run dbtool to adjust field widths (OpenEdge fields are all variable width and can be over-stuffed -- which gives SQL clients fits.)

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P24496